# How do I use Louvain Algorithm with cypher projection?

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I try to use the Louvain Algorithm with a cypher projection:

```
CALL algo.beta.louvain.stream(
'MATCH (t:Tag)
    WHERE EXISTS(t.count_primaryTag_2019)
    OR EXISTS(t.count_secondaryTag_2019)
    RETURN  id(t) AS id',
'MATCH (n:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(m:Tag) 
    WHERE EXISTS(c.count_question_2019)
    RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target',
{graph:'cypher', direction:'BOTH'})
```

My understanding of this sub-graph is, that it should be undirected and therefor I use de "direction: 'BOTH'".
But after executing the query I get the following error:

```
Neo.ClientError.Procedure.ProcedureCallFailed
Failed to invoke procedure `algo.beta.louvain.stream`: Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Incompatible directions between loaded graph and requested compute direction. Load direction: 'OUTGOING' Compute direction: 'BOTH'
```

---

My thought process was, that while building the sub-graph with the cypher projection, it creates two directed relationships for each connected node. Something like this:

> (A)-->(B); (A)<--(B)

And therefore we have a "semi-undirected" graph and therefore the Louvain Algorithm can only be executed with the 'OUTGOING' direction while working with cypher-projections.

So I tried to run the algorithm while setting the direction to 'OUTGOING':

```
CALL algo.beta.louvain.stream(
'MATCH (t:Tag)
    WHERE EXISTS(t.count_primaryTag_2019)
    OR EXISTS(t.count_secondaryTag_2019)
    RETURN  id(t) AS id',
'MATCH (n:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(m:Tag) 
    WHERE EXISTS(c.count_question_2019)
    RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target',
{graph:'cypher', direction:'OUTGOING'})
```

<s>Now I don't produce an error. Instead, no communities are getting generated at all.</s>
Now I can generate communities, but I am not certain if it is correct, what I am doing. (edited)

---

**Finally my question:**
How can I use cypher-projection with the Louvain Algorithm in Neo4j? The created sub-graph has to be undirected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Graph algorithms library is being deprecated. Please, try to use the new [Graph Data Science library](https://neo4j.com/docs/graph-data-science/current/), which is the successor of the Graph Algorithms.

Using the GDS library, the syntax would look like:

```
CALL gds.louvain.stream({
  nodeQuery:'MATCH (t:Tag)
    WHERE EXISTS(t.count_primaryTag_2019)
    OR EXISTS(t.count_secondaryTag_2019)
    RETURN  id(t) AS id',
  relationshipQuery:'MATCH (n:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(m:Tag) 
    WHERE EXISTS(c.count_question_2019)
    RETURN id(n) AS source, id(m) AS target'})
```

Regarding your question, you can ignore the direction parameter. The main part is that you have projected the relationships as undirected in your relationship cypher query, where you omit the relationship direction in the `MATCH` statement.

```
MATCH (n:Tag)-[c:CONNECTED_TO]-(m:Tag)
```

So, what you are doing is correct, but try to update your configuration and use the new and improved GDS library. If nothing else, the algorithm execution performance is better.

Comment: Thank you for this really good and fast answer and sorry for the short followup question. Can I somehow break my db, updating my configuration for using the improved libraries?

Comment: not really, it doesn't touch the database at all when updating plugins